# Creating a sketch component where it picks average colour from an image and fills it in a layer

Tags: sketch-app, gradient, symbols

I've been trying to create a symbol in sketch which has a property where an overlaying gradient layer has a fill of the average colour it picks from the image in its background. Its easy to do it manually, but is it possible to do it in a dynamic way? Basically I want to hand out the component to a designer and when they change the image in the background, I want the gradient layer to pick out the average colour from the image and create a fill. P.S. -  I tried playing with the blend properties of the layer, but it just doesn't give the required effect. Is it possible to do it with some hack? [image]

Comment: Since this is clearly for an app design, wouldn't that functionality actually need to be coded into the app itself?  So if you do it in Sketch/Photoshop manually for the sake of your design, it's irrelevant.  Just let your coder know what you want the behaviour to be.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this programmatically (yet).

---

To make your life easier though, there is a free Sketch plugin that provides you the average color of a selected image.

[image: Image Average Color in action]
[Check out Image Average Color on GitHub](https://github.com/AntonioJMartinez/sketch-ImageAverageColor)